# CloudFront strange behavior

Tags: caching, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I spent a few hours on a AWS CloudFront problem, hope someone can save me :D

When i load the site homepage, for every assets i get (on each reload):

```
X-Cache:Miss from cloudfront
```

When i try to open an asset in another tab, i then got the correct behavior (miss on first call, then hit on each reload). Same with curl requests.

I reload my home and inspect the same asset, i get:

```
X-Cache:Hit from cloudfront
```

with a similar age as in the tab.

Then i reload my homepage and inspect the same element again:

```
X-Cache:Miss from cloudfront
```

:'(

And from this point, when i reload the asset in the other tab, i get a miss...

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Jérémy

Comment: Could it be browser caching that stores misses for the first tab? I mean - are you sure response is fetched from CloudFront each time? To validate it check value of X-Amz-Cf-Id. If it is the same for each reload then it is a local cache

Comment: Are you setting the TTL on your objects properly? Given the behavior you're describing the TTL could be very low or not being set at all. Take a look at the [answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569077/cloudfront-issue-when-using-load-balancer-and-route-53/26915251#26915251).

Comment: AlexZakharenko: After re checking it,X-Amz-Cf-Id is different on each request

BruceP: I'm not an expert about caching systems, i provides assets TTL with Expires and Cache-Control headers, i think it's the right way. TTLs are between 7200 and 86400 seconds for my assets.

Maybe i misconfigured my cloudfront distribution, is it some tips ans trick about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tests on Apache configuration and CloudFront configuration, i found that cookies where causing this behavior.

Some cookies used by tracking systems change their values on each call and then cloudfront do not cache the request.

To solve it, create a custom behavior for each type of path (backend calls, assets, etc.) and create a whitelist of cookies that you really need to forward in it.

i hope this will help someone.

Thanks @AlexZakharenko and @BruceP for your replies ;)